# C++ Abstract Class as std::map key

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
struct Vehicle {
  virtual string model() = 0; // abstract
  ...
}
struct Car : public Vehicle {...}
struct Truck : public Vehicle {...}
```

I need to keep a `std::map` with some information that I acquire about some `Vehicle` instances:

```
std::map<Vehicle, double> prices;
```

However I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<const Vehicle, double>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_map.h:349:   instantiated from ‘_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = Vehicle, _Tp = double, _Compare = std::less<Vehicle>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Vehicle, double> >]’
test.cpp:10:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:73: error: cannot declare field ‘std::pair<const Vehicle, double>::first’ to be of abstract type ‘const Vehicle’
Model.hpp:28: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘const Vehicle’:
Model.hpp:32: note:     virtual string Vehicle::model()
```

So you can't use an abstract class as a `std::map` key. As far as I can tell this is because maps copy their keys (via copy-constructor or assignment operator) and this would imply instantiating an abstract class (`Vehicle`). Also even if you could, we'd fall prey to [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) anyway.

What should I do?

**It seems I can't use pointers** because there might be separate copies of logically identical  `Car`s or `Truck`s. (i.e. Two `Car` objects instantiated separately, but which represent the same car and `operator==` returns true. I need these to map to the same object in the `std::map`.)

Comment: Why not give `Vehicle` a `price` member? Or use `map<string, double>` to relate model name to price?

Comment: @Beta Pretend this is for a given search (say, in a specific geographic area). Also that doesn't solve the bitwise-copies-synchronization problem; if you have two instances of `Car`, only one would get the price.

Comment: Real cars solve this by having a registration number and a unique manufacturing serial number.

Comment: (Sorry for editing-- didn't see your comment until too late.) If a `Car` can have more than one price, depending on external stuff, then my member idea won't work, but don't think I understand your second point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You need to use pointers to `Vehicle`.
2. `operator==` is not used by the `std::map` but a compare functor which is the third parameter of the `std::map`.  By default it is `std::less`.  You need to implement your own compare functor to work with `Vehicle`:

   ```
    struct less_vehicle: std::binary_function<const Vehicle *, const Vehicle *, bool>
    {
      bool  operator() (const Vehicle *a, const Vehicle *b) const { ... }
    };
   ```

And then use it:

```
std::map<Vehicle *, double, less_vehicle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use pointers, and pass a template argument to specify the type of object that will carry out the comparison (and when you create the map, pass an object of that type to do the comparisons).

For your comparison, you'll want that to dereference the pointers and compare the objects they point at. Also note, however, that for this to succeed you'll need to define some sort of comparison between a Car and a Truck. It doesn't necessarily have to be particularly meaningful, but it does have to be consistent and transitive (the official terminology is that it must define a "strict weak ordering").

Comment: Thanks Jerry. This means I need to tell the classes apart--is the only way to do this RTTI?

Comment: @Adam, you'll need RTTI in a some form, otherwise the classes will need to know about each other to implement double dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use an ABC as a key, because having an instance of an ABC doesn't make sense.

With the line `std::map<Vehicle, double> prices;` you're saying, "make a map with `Vehicle` *instances* as keys". Since you can't have instances of `Vehicle` (as it is pure virtual), you can't have them as keys to your map either.

It's not something I've dabbled with before, but I believe using a custom allocator with the `map` you can use `Vehicle` pointers with checks for logically identical pointees.